# How should I wait for a keypress in both Python 2 and Python 3?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, input, keypress, raw-input

This is probably a very simple question, but I haven't found a simple solution. In Python2, I can wait for a keypress in the following way:

```
raw_input("\nPress Enter to continue.")
```

In Python 3, I can wait for a keypress in the following way:

```
input("\nPress Enter to continue.")
```

How should I wait for a keypress in a script that is intended to be compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3?

---

EDIT: So, for example, is the following function about as efficient as I can get?

```
def pause(
    text = "\nPress Enter to continue."
    ):
    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
        raw_input(text)
    else:
        input(text)
```

Comment: You can check what version you're on before every piece of code that is version-dependent

Comment: I would be inclined to do `if sys.version_info[0] >= 3: raw_input = input`, then use `raw_input` everywhere.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks for the suggestion. I added an example to the question illustrating that approach.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the suggestion. I think [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32716980/1556092) is basically the same idea, but with a bias towards Python versions greater than 2.

Comment: @d3pd yes, more or less - and it's *"easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"* against my *"look before you leap"*, which makes it a little more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass
```

So you'll always write

```
input('...')
```

And forget about the old and obsolete `input` on Python 2.x

Comment: Ah, that's pretty elegant and forward-looking. Thanks